# Mock or patch uuid.uuid4().hex

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to mock the `uuid4().hex`

```
@freeze_time("2022-01-01")
@patch.object(uuid, 'uuid4', side_effect=[0])
def test_get_token(d):
    assert g("username", "supersecret") == "f"
```

But I got the error

> ```
>   headers = {"iat": now.int_timestamp, "jti": uuid.uuid4().hex}
> ```
>
> E       AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'hex'

How can I mock `.hex` using pytest to return the same value everytime?

Comment: You could have the `uuid4()` function return some mock class with a `hex` property on it.

Comment: Yes, I believe that I must do it. But how? I only know the basic of mocking

Answer (score 2):

You can assign mocking values using `return_value`, for example, you could do something like this:

```
import uuid


def function():
    return uuid.uuid4().hex


@patch.object(uuid, 'uuid4')
def test_get_token(d_uuid4):
    d_uuid4.return_value.hex = '10'
    assert function() == '10'
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to be able to have multiple return values for hex so this is how I did it.

```py
@patch("uuid.uuid4")
def test(mock_uuid)
    def create_hex_mock(i: int):
        """Creates the mock for calling uuid4.hex"""
        mock_hex = MagicMock()
        mock_hex.hex = str(i)
        return mock_hex

    mock_uuid.side_effect = [create_hex_mock(i+1) for i in range(12)]
    print(mock_uuid().hex) # 1
    print(mock_uuid().hex) # 2
```